# How do you move a file in Linux using camel-exec?

Tags: linux, apache-camel

I am new to camel. I am trying to use it to move a file from one location to another in Linux. To accomplish this, I am trying to use [camel-exec](http://camel.apache.org/exec.html):

Here is what I tried:

```
from("direct:exec")
.to("exec:mv test/directorySource test/directoryDestination")
```

When I run my code, I get the following error:

```
Unable to execute command [args=[], executable = mv null null timeout=..., outFile=null. workingDir=null, useStdeirOnEmptyStdout=false]
```

Note: I am using the Java DSL, not the XML version of camel.

I have a feeling I am missing something from the command that tells it what the input should be, but I'm not sure. I tried to follow the examples in the link above for "Executing Java," but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this or what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the exception message the applciation can't find the arguments.

Try this:

```
from("direct:exec")
.to("exec:mv?args=test/directorySource test/directoryDestination")
```

See the docs [here](http://camel.apache.org/exec.html).

Comment: Thanks. Ill try it as soon as I can. But I did want to ask about the syntax. I say that page, but the "executing java" examples don't have that "?". Since my program is written in Java, shouldn't I use that syntax? Or maybe that's just for when, in your executing java code?

Comment: @JustBlossom The syntax is: `exec://executable[?options]` for options you can pass arguments, workingDir etc. - it's explained in the docs.